My Revolution Slider suddenly appears two times after updating
I updated the slider to version 6.7.9 and suddenly it appears twice on my homepage. I haven't changed anything. I use the X-theme version 10.4.20 and Cornerstone version 7.4.20.

You'll need to check with the plugin's support team. Third-party plugin and theme support are off topic here.

But the problem is that you can't get any support from them, because they only offer it to paid users. (Themeco License) But thank you for your answer, I'll try to find a solution elsewhere.

I can understand how frustrating that must me, but this isn't a "free support for plugins" site. If they've got a freeware version in the plugin repository, you might be able to find some help there.

Thank you Pat. Kind Reagards.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
